# Returning Max Matching Record from Related Model in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, swift5

Summary: In a database with a table with a many to many relationship, I need to get the most recent record of a many to many table relationship.

Tables:
I have a few tables in my database:

- A "Site" tables with a one-to-one relationship to a Locations model
- A "Location" model which contains many "Conditions"

So thus,

Site --> Location --> [Conditions]. (again, this is CoreData)

Conditions has a field lastUpdated and I would like to return the latest record, of which I would like to return the latest record

Now, I know I can do:

```
site.location   /* this returns the reference location item */
```

However, returning the condition item with the max lastUpdated field is proving an issue

I have extended my site model to return the newest "condition" based on "it's lastUpdated" field

example:

```
extension Site {
    var getLatestCondition: Condition {
        let _ = self.location  /* no error (only for "help" purposes) */ 

        /* the following returns "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" */
        return self.location.condition.max { $0.lastUpdated > $1.lastUpdated } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `max` returns an optional value so the computed property should be optional (this is the ambiguous part for the compiler)